# How to measure CPU cache misses on Windows? (AMD Ryzen 7)

Tags: c, profiling, profiler, cpu-cache, amd-processor

Are there c or c++ libraries that can read the PMC counters of AMD CPUs (Ryzen 7) such as the ones measured by `uProf`? Things such as cache misses and cpu clock cycles.

I've only come accross `AMD Master Monitoring SDK` here: https://developer.amd.com/amd-ryzentm-master-monitoring-sdk/

However it appears to only supports series 3000 Ryzen CPUs.